# Why can't I name software "hwsetup" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, permissions, development, qt

A strange thing happened to me today. I am a software developer and I develop applications using Qt. I wanted to write an unit test to one of my components, so I created a new, fresh project called "hwsetuptest", performed a build and attempted to start the test application.

However, I've got an error :

```
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
```

I couldn't figure out what is happening (the file was in place, I just could not run it), until I created a different project using the same preferences, but named it just "test", and I was able to execute it without problems.

Then I tried to create variations of projects containing string "hwsetup", and I was not able to run them again.

I asked my two colleagues to do the same thing. One of them has Windows 10, the other has Windows 7. The Windows 10 machine of my colleague was behaving exactly same as my machine, but my other colleague with his Windows 7 machine was able to run the project named "hwsetup" without problems.

So my question is : Does Microsoft forbid running software containing "hwsetup" string in Windows 10 ? If so, are there any other forbidden software names ?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior on my machine

Comment: File names containing the string like `setup`, `install` receive special treatment by Windows. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096706/how-does-windows-decide-whether-to-display-the-uac-prompt

Comment: Interesting read. Thank you for the answer !

Comment: I just created a hwsetup.exe in console app in C# on Windows 10, works fine, maybe a combination of Qt and Windows 10? `Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?` doesn't sound like a Windows error.